# How mo to perform a mouseover in Firefox with Selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox

Basically, we will need to use ActionChains move_to_element() method, but in fact it is not working in Firefox.
The code is:

```
def hover_element(self, element):
    self._driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView({block: "center"});', element)
    from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
    action = ActionChains(self._driver)
    action.move_to_element(element).perform()
```

But it is not working (only scrolls into view, of course). How can I deal with it?

Comment: can you share the xpath of element, you are trying to hover? The code looks good and do the thing.

Comment: @KumarRishabh it's not related to a locator. This code works fine for Chrome/Edge, but not for Firefox

Comment: OH that's strange.. try disabling hardware acceleration in Firefox https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/hardware-acceleration-and-windowblinds-crash or if it didn't work update your graphic driver See https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/upgrade-graphics-drivers-use-hardware-acceleration?redirectslug=how-do-i-upgrade-my-graphics-drivers&redirectlocale=en-US